# Trying to find whether the entered number is even or odd with if-else statement in C in vs code but having some issue

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", num);
    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d is even.", num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is odd.", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It supposed to give an output like the following:

```
Enter a number: 7
7 is odd.
```

but it is showing:

```
Enter a number:7
PS C:\Users\abhin\OneDrive\Desktop\cprograming\c c++>
```

and it's not showing any error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your compiler should print a warning about wrong parameter type for `scanf`. You should always listen to warnings from your compiler.

Comment: When you compile I suggest you to use always the `-Wall` option

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
 scanf("%d",num);
```

is the problem, you missed the `&` - address of operator. As per [`scanf` definition](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), you need to pass the address of the variable where you want to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you're not passing `num` as a pointer, as required by `scanf`.
You instead have to get `num`s pointer with the `&` operator like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d is even.", num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is odd.", num);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

- `scanf("%d",num)` has undefined behavior because you pass an `int` where `scanf()` expects a pointer to `int`.  The program likely crashes silenty, returning control to the shell.  Write `scanf("%d", &num)` instead.
- the compiler could have issued a warning about this mistake, but the default settings might be too slack.  Compile with all warnings enabled and correct the faulty code.  For Visual C, use `/W4`, for `gcc` and `clang`, use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.
- you should also check that `scanf("%d", &num)` returned `1` to detect invalid or missing input.
- you should output a trailing newline after the message:

  ```
  printf("%d is even.\n", num);
  ```

  on some older systems, the missing newline may cause the output to be lost or to get mixed with the shell prompt after the program exits.